# How to migrate (the content (static/HTML/Wordpress) of a) whole server to a new hosting provider?

Tags: migration

I'm currently hosting a few sites of my clients at a hosting provider that I'm not satisfied of anymore. I've got a VPS at *hosting provider X*, and I would like to migrate every website and E-mail accounts to *provider Y*. Since I'd be better safe than sorry, especially since I kind of screwed things up when moving to the VPS, a year ago.

So, a few things straight

The server contains a **Z**-panel control panel installation *(Panel already installed on new server)*, and a few static and a few Wordpress websites. Besides websites, there are a few E-mail accounts configured via Zpanel, containing many E-mails. *Anything I forgot to mention..?*

On the new server, I would like to have pretty much everything the same, *Unless you got some advice to improve performance.. :)*

So please advice me, **how do I migrate (the content of) my whole server to a new server?**

*I would say copy over the content of all databases and all files of the 'old' server. Secondly, update the DNS settings of every domain and I'm done; but I'm not 100% sure about that.*

*Comment if you need anything to create your answer*
*P.s. Anyone got experience with [DigitalOcean](http://digitalocean.com)? Since I'm migrating to them.*

Comment: This is far too broad. Your question needs to be broken down into smaller parts, email, web, database, users, etc. Honestly, my advice would be to hire someone to help you out and to teach you along the way. There are far too many ways for you to severely mess things up here.

Comment: Kudos on the win, BTW. :)

Comment: First of all, how does everyone knows so quickly I'm from The Netherlands (proud! Thanks!), or do most of you guys check someone's profile out or something? :) Anyway, on topic: Aren't there any guidelines like "Do this and you covered about 90% of all possible errors" ? Just as I'd written in the last line, where I give some actions I think that has to be done. Server configuration (such as Postfix/Dovecot, etc.) can be ignored, I guess. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully you have all the existing configuration well documented like any good sysadmin should...

To move the websites you need to copy the webserver configuration, databases, and database accounts, and files (preserving file permissions, possibly changing owner and group if needed).

For email, again copy all the configuration databases and data files.

Then test things.

Then change DNS.

All of this is much easier to do without a control panel.  But if the control panels are the same on both servers you should be able to do it.

This also makes an excellent opportunity to test restoring from your backups.  You have backups, right?  Use those backups to setup the new server, and ensure your restore procedure works and update (or write) the documentation on how to do it next time.

The biggest gotcha you might encounter is different software versions - different versions of mysql, php, apache, whatever your email is.  All of them can cause all kinds of problems.  So be sure to thoroughly test the sites on the new server before switching over to it.